# Why does my python program throw an error when running it with the debugger doesn't?

Tags: python, pickle

First I run the following snippet of code in Pycharm using the play button:

```
import os
import pickle
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

directory = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), './linear_models')
file_path = os.path.join(directory, '/factor_model/predict_car_prices.p')
with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
    lm = pickle.load(f)
print("Cat")
```

It has the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ben/Documents/programs/testload.py", line 9, in <module>
    lm = pickle.load(f)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/statsmodels/base/data.py", line 105, in __setstate__
    return_type='dataframe')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/patsy/highlevel.py", line 308, in dmatrices
    eval_env = EvalEnvironment.capture(eval_env, reference=1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/patsy/eval.py", line 226, in capture
    return cls([frame.f_locals, frame.f_globals],
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'f_locals'
```

If I run a debugger instead then the program finishes without reporting an error.

Comment: how did you create this pickle ? It seems like it is empty.

Comment: Why do you say that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that's the root cause, but I see a definite error in your code:

```py
file_path = os.path.join(directory, '/factor_model/predict_car_prices.p')
```

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join), "if a component is an absolute path, all previous components are thrown away and joining continues from the absolute path component." So `file_path` in your case actually will be `'/factor_model/predict_car_prices.p'`, which I assume is incorrect.